# react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view : Page scrolls down when I start typing

Tags: react-native, keyboard

Until typing everything is ok. However after starting typing page scrolls down(shifting). I am not able to solve this whatever i do...

```
<ImageBackground
          source={bgSrc}
          style={styles.background}
          resizeMode="cover">

         <StatusBar hidden={true} />

          <KeyboardAwareScrollView
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            enableOnAndroid
          >

            {screenToShow}

          </KeyboardAwareScrollView>

</ImageBackground>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: '100%',
    height: height,
    backgroundColor: '#555',
  },
  background: {
    flex: 1,
    width: null,
    height: null,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
});
```

[before typing, it's looking perfect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqCNw.jpg)

After typing in the password field page moves down as u see:

[after typing, it scroll down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FocfX.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

This library is always a bit janky. Try a configuration like this:

```
<KeyboardAwareScrollView
    style={{ backgroundColor: 
    themeColors.boxPrimaryBackground, flexGrow: 1 }}
    contentContainerStyle={{ width: '100%', margin: 0 }}
    scrollEnabled={true}
    extraScrollHeight={-125}
    extraHeight={10}
    keyboardOpeningTime={Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'}
>
   // add scroll content here
</ KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

The thing you really need to add is the `keyboardOpeningTime={Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER}`. It has something to do with the animation inside the library. Good luck hope this helps.

Comment: `keyboardOpeningTime={Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER}`

I've been looking for a solution for a while until I stumbled on this, which fixed it for me. Thanks a lot

Comment: keyboardOpeningTime={Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER} really saved my day. Thank you @MatijaMartic 

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your question on [github](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/issues/333) as well, and its been a long time since that is in open state there.

I have the above problem resolved using KeyboardAvoidingView from react-native

import {KeyboardAvoidingView} from 'react-native'

I have replaced KeyboardAwareScrollView with KeyboardAvoidingView and this is working as needed.

Here is an app [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ecapital.mobile&hl=en_US) that does this. You can download and see it's login page.